# 3D Plotting and optimising on the surface area of a spherical gyroid

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, modeling, system-modeling

*[**this is an *equation* of a shperical gyroid emphasized texti want to plot it in mathematica and obtain the shapes like those on the picture below. sinxcosy + sinycosz + sinzcosx = 0
i also want to know the code to use and how i can model it to obtain different surface areas. please i am in urgent need for an answer**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6gXT.png*)

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you stated the optimization problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the plot:

```
r = 2 Pi;
ContourPlot3D[
 Sin[x] Cos[y] + Sin[y] Cos[z] + Sin[z] Cos[x] == 0,
 {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r},
 RegionFunction -> ({x, y, z} \[Function] x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= r^2),
 Mesh -> None
 ]
```

[image]

For larger radius `r`, this can take quite long, though...

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. It gave me some clarification. My next question is how can i know the surface area or do a modelling and obtain different spherical gyroid shapes with different specific surface areas

Comment: Good morning sir, thank you for the answer. the code works perfectly well.i will like to know if those units are in mm or cm Now i will like to know how i can input a thickness in the above equation. There are some parameters like the Volume, thickness and the specific surface area which i need to determine.

Comment: There are no units at all. You may apply `DiscretizeGraphics` and `Area` to the `Graphics3D` object generated by `ContourPlot3D` to get area. To first order, volume is area times thickness (one can also add are lower order corrections in terms of curvature). You can also try to extrude the surface and apply `Volume` afterwards. Have a look around this site; there must somewhere a question on extruding or thickening surfaces...

Comment: thank you Sir, for the quick response. I am a beginner in Mathematica and i do not have enough skills on how to go about this. if you can please write me a code on all this so i run and see it i will be very grateful

Comment: Sorry, I do not have the time for that. Please refer to the documentations of `DiscretizeGraphics`, `Area`, and `Volume`.